# Python - Create Folder From Filename, Move File into Created Folder

Tags: python

I am trying to do my own sort of Files2Folder in python, as it would be a lot more automated for my needs. I have it so that it creates a folder from the filename, but anytime I try to move the file into the newly created folder, I am returned an error. Any ideas?

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
import glob

rootdir = r'T:\rcloneFolder'
keepExt = ('.mkv', '.mp4', '.avi')
searchPath = Path(rootdir)


for file in searchPath.rglob("*"):
    if file.name.endswith(keepExt):
        print(file)
        newName = (os.path.splitext(file.name)[0])
        newFolders = os.mkdir(os.path.join(searchPath,newName))
        print("Made File Directory: " + newName)
        name = newName + '.mkv'
        shutil.move(file, os.path.join(rootdir, name))
```

Comment: what error are you getting? I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I am getting this error with that code: AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information: what should the code do, what error do you get (full error trace please!). If possible try to create a [mre]. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is that you need to use `rootdir` instead of `searchPath` to `os.path.join` since join expects a plain string, then the new filename is going to be `os.path.join(rootdir, newName, newName) + ".mkv"` since you want to rename the extension and move it into the folder with the same name, so the following code I believe would do what you are looking for:

```
for file in searchPath.rglob("*"):
    if file.name.endswith(keepExt):
        print(file)
        name = (os.path.splitext(file.name)[0])
        newFolder = os.path.join(rootdir,name)
        os.mkdir(newFolder)
        print("Made File Directory: " + newFolder)
        destination = os.path.join(newFolder, name) + '.mkv'
        shutil.move(file, destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
import glob, os
import shutil

for file in glob.glob('*.webm'):
    folder_name = file.split('.')[0]
    Path(folder_name).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    shutil.move(file, folder_name)
```

Comment: This did not work. I am not sure with this where to even enter my path. The Script is not in the same path as the files.

Comment: os.chdir(your_folder)

add this before the loop

Comment: This returns no errors, but nothing happens with it either. The script says it runs, and no folders are created, so no files are moved into folders either.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Can you explain what the error in the question was and how your code solves the problem?

Comment: if you want the folder to be called 'test.webm' instead of just 'test', replace folder_name with file